# DOM & XPath scraping - Bringing back both li elements text, when only want the one

Tags: php, dom, xpath, screen-scraping

Here is my code so far.

```
$dom_currys = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom_currys->loadHTMLFile('http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/apple-new-ipod-touch-8gb-4th-generation-07677427-pdt.html');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath_currys = new DOMXpath($dom_currys);
$nodes_currys = $xpath_currys->query(
    '/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li/span'
);
$currys_stock_data = $nodes_currys->item(0)->nodeValue; // "Available for home delivery"

echo $currys_stock_data;
```

When echoed, it comes back with

```
Â Available for home delivery
Â Available to reserve & collect
```

I only require the "Available for home delivery" part. Each is in a separate "li" element, however still it brings back both, the XPath if I wanted the second one would be

```
/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li[2]/span
```

I suspect its to do with selecting the correct item, but not sure if its right or not.

Also I require that the result be checked by an IF statement. What I have so far:

```
if (strpos($currys_stock_data, 'Available for home') !== false) {
    $currys_stockyesno = "Yes";
} else {
    $currys_stockyesno = "No";
}
echo $currys_stockyesno;
```

I thought it would be best to check if it contained "Available for home delivery" rather than a straight match, because the website can sometimes say its available for home delivery in 2 days, along those lines. So long as the string contained that string, then it would return as true/yes. But it's saying no...

Comment: Why don't you just select the first one in documento order with `/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li[1]/span`?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

I looked a the site you are scrapping and found that the `li` is actually what contains the text. The `span` has a class on it for the icon. Since the check mark icon changes, we need to check for this too. However, it doesn't seem like you actually need the text, you need to check if the item allows home delivery.

```
$xpath = "//li[contains(., 'Available for home delivery')]/span[class='icon icon-check']";
```

Then, just check the length:

```
if( $nodes_currys->length === 1 ) // true if available for home.
```

I should also note that this method will not work on their search/browse pages since they use images there.....very confusing and why I hate scraping :P

Answer (score 0):

**I have examined the HTML source and confirmed that**

```
/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li
```

selects *two* elements.

**If you want to select only the first of the two text nodes, use**:

```
/html/body
      /div/div/div[2]
                /div/div/div[2]
                          /div/ul[2]/li[1]
                                      /span/following-sibling::text()
```